# OSMasterMap.ttf not recognised in QGIS - macOS Sierra

Tags: qgis, font, os-mastermap

I am currently learning how to work with OSMastermap Data with postgreSQL and postGIS. After much tinkering I have finally got OS Translator II working and have the Topographic data converted and in the database, with style applied.

The only issue I have now is I can't seem to get OSMasterMap.ttf to work properly within QGIS. It recognises that the font is present, but it does not apply the font when rendering, it reverts back to normal letters.

When I go to select a font it can be selected from the drop down, but the symbols are not used.

[image: Font can be selected from dropdown]

The font is installed on the system, as it can be seen in the font book.

[image: Font is installed on system]

Does anyone know if there is a solution to this problem?

Comment: I also noticed this when I used OS Translator II plugin to do the same into a PostGIS database. I am using QGIS on Windows. So this is not exclusive to macOS. I am able to manually assign the SVG symbols.

Comment: I was digging around the settings and I have found that the symbols from the font are showing up in QGIS, they aren't being applied by the style correctly. See image link. You can manually change them if you know which symbol is used for each catagraphicsymbol and the missing topographicpoints.

https://imgur.com/a/8TJPk

Comment: I have checked back to look at an OSMM dataset that I loaded to a local PostGIS database about a year ago and the SVG symbols are fine in that? I can't see what is different at the moment. I am going to keep trying a few things. I wonder if it has anything to do with the latest schema 9 that has just been released?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a bit of looking into this and it is probably due to you having used the latest OSMM style schema 9, just released in March 2017, which is not currently supported by the plugin.

See 
http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/products/ostranslator-ii/

I have been in touch with, the plugin's creators Lutra Consulting, who we have a support package with, and they are working on Schema 9. They tell me it should be ready very soon.

In the meantime, if you can't wait then use the SVG's and font from Schema 7, this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am sure that the font I used was the Schema 7 font. I will uninstall the font from my system, download and reinstall the Schema 7 font to make sure.